# Control the <p> tags added by Tex4HT

Tags: paragraphs, html, tex4ht

TeX4HT allows to reset LaTeX macros to insert HTML code in order to produce clean HTML documents. This is great, but it often gets in a mess of `<p>` tags, such as:

```
<p class="noindent" ><hr />Some text</p>
```

after I set a command to insert `<hr />`. Here I'd like `<hr />` to be outside any `<p>` tag.

There's worse. Sometimes it just generates code which is plain wrong, like:

```
<p class="noindent"><span class="small-caps"></p><p class="noindent">Some text</p></span>
```

after I set a command to set small caps.

Is there a way to control these `<p>` tags to make them behave properly?

Comment: Do you use custom commands and configurations or just standard LaTeX? Can you post mwe?

Comment: It's not standard, there's quite a few personal commands. The code is on https://github.com/cc-translators/sagesse. It is built by typing `make sagesse_lulu.html`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Paragraph handling is little bit tricky with `tex4ht`. Some information can be found in the article [TeX4ht configure: Part 1](http://www.cvr.cc/tex4ht-configure-part-1/).

There are two issues, if command with configuration hooks is at the beginning of the paragraph.

If some hook is inserted at the beginning of the paragraph, it must place the

tag manually, with some of commands described in the article. The code usually looks like:

```
\Configure{chapHook}{%
\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP\Tg<h2 class="dvmonth">}{\Tg</h2>\IgnoreIndent}
```

This will include block level element with no paragraphs inside, `\IgnoreIndent` will cause next paragraph to have `class="noindent"`.

For inline elements, it can look:

```
\Configure{sample}{\ifvmode \ShowPar\fi \HCode{<i>}}{\Tg</i>}
```

There is probably bug with `\Tg<>` command, which causes that its content gets before

tag. Solution is to use `\HCode` instead in the hooks which are inserted at beginning of the paragraphs.

```
%Wrong, gives: <i><p>
\Configure{sample}{\ifvmode \ShowPar\fi \Tg<i>}{\Tg</i>}
%Good:
\Configure{sample}{\ifvmode \ShowPar\fi \HCode{<i>}}{\Tg</i>}
```

Edit:
As Ulrike Fisher pointed out in comments, there are some details about configuring.

If you have some custom commands and you want to provide configurations for them, it is best to collect them in some package like `mycommands.sty`. Then you can provide file `mycommands.4ht`, which is called automatically by `tex4ht` when you include `mycommands.sty`.

For every configuration, you need to provide three things:

1. Create configuration hooks. This is done with

   `\NewConfigure{sample}{2}`

   This will create configuration hooks `\a:sample` and `\b:sample`.
2. Redefine command to include configuration hooks:

   `\renewcommand\sample[1]{\a:sample#1\b:sample}`
3. Provide default configuration for hooks

   `\Configure{sample}{\Tg<tag name>}{\tg</tag name>}`

This configuration will be then used as default.

You can redefine default configuration in custom config file, which is specified at command line when running `tex4ht`.

mysample.cfg:

```
\Preamble{xhtml, charset=utf-8}
\Configure{sample}{\Tg<another tag>}{\Tg</another tag>}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

To be compiled with

```
htlatex myfile "mysample, other options" " -cunihtf -utf8"
```

Last possibility to put configuration somewhere in your `tex` file in block that is called only when running with `tex4ht`

```
...
\@ifpackageloaded{tex4ht}{
\Configure{sample}{\HCode{<bla bla>}}{\HCode{</bbla bla>}
}{}
...
```

note that there are some commands disabled, like `\Css` and this method is best be used for testing purposes only

Comment: Now my documents are valid XHTML 1.0 documents!

Comment: Someone should write a book about TeX4HT, it's a great tool once you know how to use it!

Comment: Maybe we could start with community wiki here, I would add some details about creating configurations etc., but my knowledge in other areas like font handling is really limited.

Comment: @michal.h21: It would be great if you can add infomations about configuring. Beside the actual code: could you also add some ideas how to organize the code. E.g. where to put new/changed configuration code if it should affect only one document or if it should be used for all documents or if you simply want to do a fast test.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I added some details