# Htlatex and subcaption - can htlatex be extended?

Tags: tex4ht, subcaption

To start with MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-tex4ht.def}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\subcaptionbox{Small} { \tikz \draw (0cm,0cm) circle(5mm); }
\subcaptionbox{Big}   { \tikz \draw (0cm,0cm)  circle(20mm); }
\caption{Circles}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This works to some degree with `htlatex`. However, `subcaption`-package gives warnings and I must press enter several times to get this compiled. Also, this could generate something like `<TD>Small . . . <TD COLSPAN=2>Circles...`, but does not.

As a second and easier example, `\subpdfbookmark` gives error with `htlatex`.

Is it possible to modify htlatex and/or packages and get this working properly?

Comment: have you tried `compatibility=false`?

Comment: At least `\usepackage[compatibility=false]{caption}` removes the errors but IMHO the result is not very satisfying... But when using `subfig` and `\subfloat` the result seems to be the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have old version of `subcaption`, but your example fails even with pdflatex for me, saying you need to load package caption first. So fixed code looks this way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-tex4ht.def}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\subcaptionbox{Small} { \tikz \draw (0cm,0cm) circle(5mm); }
\subcaptionbox{Big}   { \tikz \draw (0cm,0cm)  circle(20mm); }
\caption{Circles}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
this compiles without error for me with0 `texlive 2010`, but with `texlive 2012` using `subcaption` package with `htlatex` gives error, saying it is needed to include `caption` package with `compatibility=false` option. So you need to change your preamble to include this option with `tex4ht` run:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ifdefined\HCode
\usepackage[compatibility=false]{caption}
\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-tex4ht.def}
\else
\usepackage[]{caption}
\fi
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
```

note that also `pgfsys-tex4ht.def` is used only with `tex4ht` now.

Now there are three problems

1. second svg image fails to render, because there is a `</p>` tag
2. subcaptions are enclosed in `tspan` elements, these are svg, not html elements and shouldn't be in the document
3. there is a lack of logical markup which could be styled using `css`

so we need to configure `tex4ht` to output logical markup and as a consequence solve issues 1 and 2.

Standard way to configure a package for `tex4ht` is to provide file named `packagename.4ht`. So `subcaption.4ht` in our case:

```
\NewConfigure{subcaptionbox}{3}
\renewcommand\subcaptionbox[2]{%
\a:subcaptionbox#2\b:subcaptionbox#1\c:subcaptionbox
}

\Configure{subcaptionbox}
{\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP\HCode{<div class="subcaptionbox">\Hnewline<div class="image">}}
{\HCode{</div>\Hnewline<div class="subcaption">}}
{\HCode{</div>\Hnewline</div>\Hnewline}}

\Css{.subcaptionbox{display:inline-block;}}
\Css{.subcaption{text-align:center;}}
```

we declared three hooks which are used for inserting html tags with `\NewConfigure`, then redefined `\subcaptionbox` to use these hooks and with `\Configure{subcaptionbox}` we insert the html tags. Construct

```
\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP
```

is there to solve problem with `</p>` tags on wrong positions. see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66172/2891) for more details.

You can play with `\Css` commands and add some more fancy formatting.

Code generated with this configuration:

```xml
<div class="subcaptionbox"> 
<div class="image"> <object data="subcap-1.svg" width="39.47014 " height="39.47014 " type="image/svg+xml"><p>SVG-Viewer needed.</p></object> </div> 
<div class="subcaption">Small</div> 
</div> 
 <div class="subcaptionbox"> 
<div class="image"> <object data="subcap-2.svg" width="153.28075 " height="153.28075 " type="image/svg+xml"><p>SVG-Viewer needed.</p></object> </div> 
<div class="subcaption">Big</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Very interesting. This gives me errors, but in any case compiles and works as you said. I have Fedora Linux with TeXlive, and `subcation.sty` is from `tex-caption-3.2e.svn25657-1.noarch.rpm`. What version are you using?

Comment: @JoriMäntysalo with texlive 2010, it compiled correctly, with texlive 2012, there is error caused with subcaption inclusion. I think this is some bug in tex4ht

Comment: Thanks! Next I will try to understand _how_ this system works...