# Quoting environment and tex4ht

Tags: tex4ht, quoting

I'm trying to convert some latex which includes the [quoting](http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/quoting/quoting.pdf) environment, to html using *htlatex*. Here's a little example which gets typeset without any problems:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{quoting}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter one}
Here is a para

Here is a second para

\begin{quoting}
one para inside a small block.

another para inside the block.
\end{quoting}

Now for a para after the quote.

And another para after the quote.

What has happened? In the HTML version there are no para breaks!

\chapter{Chapter two}
Let's try after a chapter break.

That's good -- para breaks work now.

But what happened after the quoting environment in the previous chapter?
\end{document}
```

When I tried to run htlatex on this file it didn't know about the *quoting* environment, so I created this tex4ht config file *configexample.cfg*:

```
\Preamble{html}

\begin{document} 
\ConfigureEnv{quoting}
    {\HCode{<blockquote>}}
    {\HCode{</blockquote>}}{}{}

\EndPreamble
```

Running this as `htlatex example.tex "configexample.cfg"` appears to work, and it creates *example.html*, and even gets the blockquote tags in there. But after the end of the quoting environment, I don't get the p tags I expected. Not, that is, until after a chapter break.

I don't know whether this is a tex4ht issue, or an issue with the *quoting* package. I could go back to using the *quote* environment, but I'd like to make this work first, if I can. Any ideas?

(Running under MiKTeX)

Comment: I think this is the same issue http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66131/2891

Comment: I'd seen that issue and it's not the same. In this case there are simply no <p> tags after the quoting environment, until something gets reset by a chapter break.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, it seems that `quoting` pretty  aggressively redefines `\everypar` token register, which is used by `tex4ht` to insert `<p>` tags. So we must create file `quoting.4ht` which will be loaded automatically with `quoting.sty`:

```
\newtoks\quoting@parht
\NewConfigure{quoting}{2}
\Configure{quoting}
{\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP\HCode{<blockquote>}\HtmlParOn}
{\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP\HCode{</blockquote>}\HtmlParOn\par}

\ConfigureEnv{quoting}
{\quoting@parht=\everypar%
\a:quoting\par\ShowPar}
{\par%
\b:quoting%
\everypar=\quoting@parht\par\ShowPar}
{}{}

\ConfigureList{quoting}{}{}
{%
\everypar=\quoting@parht\par\ShowPar%
}{}
```

First, we define new token register `quoting@parht`, where value of `\everypar` is saved, then new configuration `quoting` is created, so we can configure only tags to be inserted.

Then with `\ConfigureEnv` we save value of `\everypar`, then insert start and end tag, and restore value of `everypar`, so html paragraphs are printed. We must also use `\ConfigureList`, so paragraphs work correctly also inside the environment. The result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<!--http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd-->  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
> 
<head><title></title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari/TeX4ht/)" /> 
<meta name="originator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari/TeX4ht/)" /> 
<!-- xhtml,html --> 
<meta name="src" content="quot.tex" /> 
<meta name="date" content="2013-10-29 15:45:00" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="quot.css" /> 
</head><body 
>


  <h2 class="chapterHead"><span class="titlemark">1</span>&#x00A0;&#x00A0;<a 
 id="x1-10001"></a>Chapter one</h2>
<!--l. 6--><p class="noindent" >Here is a para
</p><!--l. 8--><p class="indent" >  Here is a second para
</p>
  <blockquote>
     <!--l. 11--><p class="indent" >
     one para inside a small block.
     </p><!--l. 13--><p class="indent" >  another para inside the block.
     </p><!--l. 15--><p class="indent" >  and another para
</p>
  </blockquote>
<!--l. 18--><p class="indent" >  Now for a para after the quote.
</p><!--l. 20--><p class="indent" >  And another para after the quote.
</p><!--l. 22--><p class="indent" >  What has happened? In the HTML version there are no para breaks!


</p>
  <h2 class="chapterHead"><span class="titlemark">2</span>&#x00A0;&#x00A0;<a 
 id="x1-20002"></a>Chapter two</h2>
<!--l. 25--><p class="noindent" >Let&apos;s try after a chapter break.
</p><!--l. 27--><p class="indent" >  That&apos;s good &#8211; para breaks work now.
</p><!--l. 29--><p class="indent" >  But what happened after the quoting environment in the previous chapter? </p> 
</body></html>
```