# What exactly do \EndP and \IgnorePar do?

Tags: tex4ht

What exactly do `\IgnorePar` and `\EndPar` do?
Many configurations start like this:

```
\Configure{foo}{%
\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP
...
```

I'm trying to learn `TeX4ht` to improve conversion to OpenDocument Text, and kind of slogging through the sparse documentation available. Most people just copy-paste the literary sources here:

```
  \EndP
  \IgnorePar     Asks to ignore the next paragraph
  \ShowPar       Asks to take into account the following paragraphs
  \SaveEndP      Saves the content of EndP, and sets it to empty content
  \RecallEndP
  \SaveHtmlPar
  \RecallHtmlPar
```

which doesn't help much.

Comment: have you seen this answer of mine? http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66172/2891

Comment: Just read it. Thanks. I concur with the people who commented on your answer that we need a baby-step introduction and how-to to `TeX4ht`. Those available online assume too much from new comers. How "next" and "following" differ in the lines above, for instance, is cryptic.

Comment: you are right. I plan to write some introduction, but it difficult for as English is not my native language and I still don't completely understand many internal processes of `tex4ht`