# LaTeX to HTML using htlatex - Background problem

Tags: highlighting, tex4ht, minted, htlatex

I've been trying to highlight Python code and convert it to HTML. 
For highlighting I used the `minted` package since it provided a few styles that I was looking for and I used `htlatex` for HTML conversion. Unfortunately, the background is not set as intended.

When using `htlatex`, I get the following warning:

> ```
> "Missing \Configure{\HColor}{DarkGrey}{...} (in Latex: gray 0.1)"
> ```

Here is the TeX file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{DarkGray}{gray}{0.1}
\usemintedstyle{monokai}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}
[
frame=lines,
framesep=2mm,
baselinestretch=1.2,
bgcolor=DarkGray
]
{python}

[random python code here...]

\end{minted}    
\end{document}
```

`htlatex` is called like so:

```
htlatex test.tex "" "" "" -shell-escape
```

I am a complete newbie when it comes to latex and I'm probably missing something obvious here. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: @yo Thanks :) Not new to stackexchange sites in general but I should be sticking around here for a while until I am more proficient with LaTeX !

Comment: Well, usually we include a link with the welcome message, that is intended to the newbies. I noticed that you came with 101 rep, so you're not that much new to SE ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `minted` uses `\colorbox` for colored background, which is supported by `tex4ht`, we only need to configure it to support `DarkGray` color.

Create file `hello.cfg`:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{HColor}{DarkGray}{\#1A1A1A}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

and compile with

```
htlatex test.tex "hello" "" "" -shell-escape
```

`\#1A1A1A` is hexadecimal value of your dark gray color. Unfortunately, this isn't all what needs to be done. `minted` package doesn't have it's own configuration file for `tex4ht`, but uses supported packages, so it more or less works. There is a problem with your example though. Generated code listing doesn't have gray background. Why? It is evident from generated `html` code:

```xml
<p class="noindent" >
<span 
class="colorbox" id="colorbox8"></p><div class="minipage"><div class="fancyvrb" id="fancyvrb1"><a
```

`<span class="colorbox">` which is our colorbox is immediately closed by `</p>` tag! To solve that, we need to configure `minted` environment to close previous paragraph. This is common issue, see [Control the `<p>` tags added by tex4ht](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66172/2891).

Modify the config file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{HColor}{DarkGray}{\#1A1A1A}
\ConfigureEnv{minted}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP}{}{}{}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

This closes the paragraph before `minted` environment, resp. doesn't create one, as in your example there are no paragraphs:

```xml
<span 
class="colorbox" id="colorbox8"><div class="minipage"><div class="fancyvrb" id="fancyvrb1"><a 
 id="x1-4r1"></a><span
```

of course, it still doesn't work, probably because of some html or css rules. Fortunately, solution is easy, we just need to declare `span.colorbox` to have `display:block` css property:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{HColor}{DarkGray}{\#1A1A1A}
\ConfigureEnv{minted}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP}{}{}{}
\Css{span.colorbox{display:block;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

and the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the incredible answer! I sure have a lot of things to read about.