# How to write custom configuration for TeX4ht

Tags: macros, tex4ht, htlatex

I have some macros in my document, and I want to create my own HTML for there. I follow [this blog entry](http://www.cvr.cc/?p=482) but I can't to make it work.

I put this code before my `\begin{document}`:

```
    \def\one#1#2#3{#1space#2space#3}

    \NewConfigure{one}[4]%
         {\def\a@one{#1}\def\b@one{#2}%
          \def\c@one{#3}\def\d@one{#4}}

    % I can't understand this things too much - I'm not familiar with TeX
    \def\@temp#1#2#3{\a@one#1\c@one#2\d@one#3\b@one}  
       \let\one\@temp

    \Configure{one}
       {\Tg<span class="one">\Tg<code>}{\Tg</b>\Tg</span>}
       {\Tg</code>\Tg<em>}{\Tg</em>\Tg<b>} 

    \one{verbatim}{emphasize}{boldface}
```

And compile with: `htlatex mylatexfile.tex "xhtml"`

And I get this error message:

```
    ! Use of \one doesn't match its definition.
    l.19         \one{
                      verbatim}{emphasize}{boldface}
```

My problem is, for example, I have a macro like:

```
    \newcommand{\myfunction}[2]{The title is: #1 an the body is \textit{#2} }
```

and I want to translate this in some like:

```
    <div class="container">
       <div class="title"><!-- #1 goes here --></div>
       <div class="content"><!-- #2 goes here --></div>
    </div>
```

How I can do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`tex4ht` works best when your macros are saved in a `.sty` file and `tex4ht` configurations for these macros are saved in file named as the `.sty` file, only with `.4ht` suffix. In your situation, you may put your macro `\myfunction` to `mystyle.sty`:

```
\newcommand{\myfunction}[2]{The title is: #1 an the body is \textit{#2} }
```

now what to put to `mystyle.4ht`? You need to declare configurations for inserted html tags, redefine `\myfunction` to insert these tags and provide default values for configurations:

```
\NewConfigure{myfunction}{3}

\renewcommand\myfunction[2]{\a:myfunction#1\b:myfunction#2\c:myfunction}

\Configure{myfunction}{\HCode{<div class="container">\Hnewline
   <div class="title">}}{\HCode{</div>
   <div class="content">}}{\HCode{</div>
</div>}}
```

simplified form of `\NewConfigure` is used here, with number in `{}` brackets you declare commands `\a:name`, `\b:name`, ... We need to declare three insertions, before and after parameters and between them.

For more information see my [tex4ht tutorial](https://github.com/michal-h21/helpers4ht/wiki/tex4ht-tutorial). You may also need to modify the provided configurations for `\Configure{myfunction}` because of paragraphs handling see [Control the `<p>` tags](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66131/2891)