# tex4ht: Wrapping several paragraphs inside a div tag

Tags: paragraphs, tex4ht, html

I want to wrap several paragraphs inside a div with a custom class, but the div is closed automatically in the resulting HTML when a new paragraph begins.

This shows the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\Hcode{<div class='FOO'>}
\begin{center}
test
\end{center}
\Hcode{</div>}
\end{document}
```

The 'FOO'-div is closed before the 'center'-div is opened.

The [tex4ht tutorial](https://github.com/michal-h21/helpers4ht/wiki/tex4ht-tutorial) begins to explain what I believe is what I need, but ends with "This exercise will be little bit more difficult".

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The paragraphs must be handled [in a specific way](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66172/2891) in `tex4ht`. They must be closed before a block element starts. Details are in the linked answer.

I would introduce a custom environment in this case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{myblock}{\center}{\endcenter}
\begin{document}

\begin{myblock}
test

another paragraph
\end{myblock}
\end{document}
```

It can be then configured in the `.cfg` file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\ConfigureEnv{myblock}
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="foo">}\par}
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</div>}\par}{}{}
\Css{.foo{text-align:center;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The `\ConfigureEnv` command can be used to configure any environment, the `\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP` will handle the paragraph closing before the block element start or end. `\par` command will ensure a new paragraph opening inside and after the environment.

This is the resulting HTML:

```xml
<body>
   <div class="foo">
<!--l. 6--><p class="noindent" >test
</p><!--l. 8--><p class="noindent" >another paragraph
</p>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: I had to replace the quotes by single quotes, or else I'd get broken HTML: `<div class="foo\global \let \T1\frqq \T1\guillemotright \T1\frqq &lt;!--l. 23--&gt;&lt;p class=" noindent"="">`. But I now got it to work the way I wanted. Thanks for the swift response! Very nice work with make4ht, too.

Comment: @Volker oh really? this shouldn't happen. what was the command you used for the compilation? including options

Comment: `make4ht -l -u -f html5 -d html doc.tex "" "" "" "-file-line-error -halt-on-error"`

Comment: Never mind, with the `article` class it works fine. I was using a custom document class with lots of dependencies. Not sure where the problem is...

Comment: @Volker this can be an issue with Babel package, it often redefines characters like parenthesis to produce desired output. it can break things like this.